# Jumping to exact part of program in python

Tags: python, function

My problem is that if I input wrong values for x1 or x2 my program successfully jumps to Func1() but when I input them correctly second time program returns None. 
I know why he returns None but I don't know how to fix this problem without writing another 20-30 lines of code. I am searching for some elegant solution. Thx

```
def Func1():
    value1=input('x1>')
    value2=input('x2>')
    if x1 meets condition:
        if x2 meets condition:
            return x1+x2
    else:
        Func1()

def Func2(data2):
    do somthing...

def main():

    user=ActiveUser()
    data1=Func1()
    data2=Func2(data1)
    DoSomething(data1,data2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an actual reproducible working example, unlike every other answer here so far that doesn't actually run:

The condition is that both number must be greater than 10:

```
 def Func1():
   v1 = input("v1> ")
   v2 = input("v2> ")
   if v1 > 10 and v2 > 10:
     return v1 + v2
   else:
     print "Try again"
     return Func1()
```

Test run:

```
>>> Func1()
v1> 1
v2> 2
Try again
v1> 2
v2> 3
Try again
v1> 12
v2> 23
35
```

I don't think implementing this as a recursive call is a good idea anyway. Use a while loop?

Comment: Thank you, part that I needed is return Func1() instead of my idea where I used just Func1().

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job:

```
def Func1():
    value1=None
    value2=None
    while not (x1 meets condition and x2 meets condition):
        value1=input('x1>')
        value2=input('x2>')
    return x1+x2

def Func2(data2):
    do somthing...

def main():
    user=ActiveUser()
    data1=Func1()
    data2=Func2(data1)
    DoSomething(data1,data2)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :D

Answer (score 1):

You dont return the recursive call to func1.

And the x1 and x2 tests then need to be in the same statement. Otherwise if `x1 meets cond` but `!x2 meets cond` you still don't return anything.

```
def Func1():
    value1=input('x1>')
    value2=input('x2>')
    if x1 meets condition and x2 meets condition:
        return x1+x2
    else:
        return Func1()
```

Comment: Thank you, part that I needed is return Func1() instead of my idea where I used just Func1().